# How do I do two different selects?

Tags: postgresql

In postgresql how do I do something like below? I MUST be able to return a string (when there's a logical error) and multiple rows on my typical case.

```
\set placeholder 5

IF :placeholder<1000 THEN
   select 'Value to small';
ELSE 
   select unnest(ARRAY[2,8,9]);
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT fields_of_your_choice,
 CASE
  WHEN (placeholder<1000) THEN 'Value to small'
  ELSE  unnest(array_field_name)
 END AS p
FROM your_table;
```

Comment: using the below I got the error `ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "Value to small"`. I 100% would like to return different types with one select being a single column and the other being 1 or many column with many rows

 SELECT 0,
  CASE
   WHEN (:placeholder<1000) THEN 'Value to small'
   ELSE  3
  END AS p

Comment: you can't return different types. In your case I suggest always return `text`, means `ELSE '3' END AS p` , then in case you need to make some operations on postgres side, use casting

Comment: I'm not very good with psql. Could I have some kind of function or store procedure which has an early exit returning "foo" and `1,2,3` on the regular case?